# Dynamically reference cell in different workbook

Tags: excel

I have two workbooks:

1. WorkbookToUpdate.xls
2. Workbook_for_20130901.xls

In the first workbook I have the following:

```
A1 ='[Workbook_for_20130901]Sheet1'!$C5
```

Now a month goes by and I want to update the first work to reference Workbook_for_20131001.xls without going cell by cell and changing the name of the workbook. My thought was to make the date portion of the workbook name a variable and simply change that variable, but that doesn't seem to be working.

EDIT: I don't want to use Excel's INDIRECT function because I don't want to open the reference workbook.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution to be Harlan Grove’s PULL function (code can be found [here](http://numbermonger.com/2012/02/11/excel-pull-function-creating-dynamic-links-to-closed-workbooks/)), which works similarly to the INDIRECT function except that it doesn't require the source workbook to be open. The other solution, which actually works out to be faster than the Pull function (its only downfall) is the one I was using originally - Good ol' "find & replace". I thought that that was slow, but after trying the Pull function, it's not too bad.

Another option is by changing the source through excel's Data links, but this doesn't allow you to choose which cells keep the old source and which cells use the new one (in my case, I need the old values as well).